# Flutter(Dart) - How to read from a list in a list?

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart

So I have data in this format:

```
List users = [
  {
   "id": "p1",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "age": "44",
   "imageUrl": [
   {
    "assets/images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png",
    "assets/images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash.png",
  }
 ],
 "profession": "Financial Consultant"
 },

{
 "id": "p2",
 "name": "John Doe2",
 "age": "42",
 "imageUrl": [
  {
    "assets/images/good-faces-hiba-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png",
    "assets/images/good-faces-hiba-unsplash.jpg",
  }
 ],
 "profession": "Financial Consultant"
 },
];
```

How do I read the imageUrls?

```
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(lstUsers[index]["imageUrl"][0]),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: try to use `List<Map<String,String>>` instead of `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that the imageUrl array is structured like that:

```
"imageUrl": [
  {
    "assets/images/good-faces-hiba-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png",
    "assets/images/good-faces-hiba-unsplash.jpg",
  }
],
```

The first item in the imageUrl array is not a String its a Set (Because it's surrounded with curly braces).
If you want to access the first asset in the imageUrl list remove the curly braces and make the imageUrl look like that:

```
"imageUrl": [
    "assets/images/good-faces-hiba-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png",
    "assets/images/good-faces-hiba-unsplash.jpg",
],


// Now when you use that it will return a String
lstUsers[index]["imageUrl"][0];
```

If you want to keep the structure of the list the same way and you still want to access the first imageUrl you can use the following syntax:

```
lstUsers[index]["imageUrl"][0].first;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, Dart is treating that field as a Set `{}` or more specifically as a `LinkedHashSet`.
A set does not implements the `[]` operator but you could access its elements using the method `elementAt`.

```dart
lstUsers[0]["imageUrl"][0].elementAt(1)
```

Up until `lstUsers[0]["imageUrl"][0]` you have selected the first element inside the array, but note that the array its not just made of strings, is one set with the strings inside it.

```json
[{    "assets/images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png",
    "assets/images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash.png",  }]
```

Thats the reason you then have to use `.elementAt()` to access the strings.
I would recommend if its in your power to drop the `{}` arount the strings so theyre easier to access.
Or even better create classes that manage the serialization and deserialization of the JSON. A nice place to start is [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io).